# I am not able to get why showing exception while I parcing JSON like "JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray" in my android project

Tags: android

Here is my code where I am stuck:
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                      Faq = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FAQ);

```
                for (int i = 0; i < Faq.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Faq.getJSONObject(i);

                    String questions = c
                            .getString("TAG_QUESTIONS");
                    String answer = c.getString("TAG_ANSWER");
                    HashMap<String, String> Faq = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    faqList.add(Faq);

                }
```

Thank you all of your ur replay please check above code...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: because it is not an `JSONObject` it is an completely wrong `JSONArray`

Comment: Your object is located in an json array , first get the array and then the object

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more. What is the code causing your error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "creationDate": null,
                "updationDate": null,
                "creationUserId": null,
                "updation‌​UserId": null,
                "questions": "What is Android",
                "answer": "Android is a mobile operating system (OS) based on the Linux kernel and currently developed by Google. ",
                "deactivated": false
            }
        ]
        //this your json array i parse in following format
        package com.example.jsondemo;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;


        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                String jsonobj="[{\"id\":1,\"creationDate\":null,\"updationDate\":null,\"creationUserId\":null,\"updationUserId\":null,\"questions\":\"What is Android\",\"answer\":\"Android is a mobile operating system (OS) based on the Linux kernel and currently developed by Google.\",\"deactivated\":false}]";

// yuor json is correct. don't confuse about above json string jsut I created    //json string for your understanding

                try {
                    JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonobj);

                    for (int count = 0; count < ja.length(); count++)

                     {

                     JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(count);

                    int ID = obj.getInt("id");
                    String CreationDate=obj.getString("creationDate");
                    String UpdationDate=obj.getString("updationDate");
                    String CreationUserId=obj.getString("creationUserId");
                    String Questions=obj.getString("questions");
                    String Answer = obj.getString("answer");
                    boolean Deactivated=obj.getBoolean("deactivated");
                    Log.d("test", "user id"+" "+ID);
                    Log.d("test", CreationDate);
                    Log.d("test", UpdationDate);
                    Log.d("test", CreationUserId);
                    Log.d("test", Questions);
                    Log.d("test", Answer);
                    Log.d("test","check"+ " "+Deactivated);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
        //please check logcat test value it sucessfull work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//lakshman it work proprly please check it
 String JsonStr="[{"id":1,"creationDate":null,"updationDate":null,"creationUserId":null,"updationUserId":null,"questions":"What is Android","answer":"Android is a mobile operating system (OS) based on the Linux kernel and currently developed by Google.","deactivated":false}]";


  JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(JsonStr);

    for (int count = 0; count < jArr.length(); count++)

     {

     JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(count);

   int id= obj.getString("id");

    String imageName = obj.getString("creationDate");
    //like that same
    }
```

Comment: mahadev please check my newly updated code..
and give me suggestion for that

Comment: please send your json data i will check

Comment: [{"id":1,"creationDate":null,"updationDate":null,"creationUserId":null,"updationUserId":null,"questions":"What is Android","answer":"Android is a mobile operating system (OS) based on the Linux kernel and currently developed by Google. ","deactivated":false}]